# Warning Reactjs - undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project for School and I have some problems with them.

So this is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Container, Toolbar, Typography, MenuItem, Select, makeStyles, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { CryptoState } from '../CryptoContext';

//Creeare Design - Titlu
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  title: {
    flex:1,
    color: "gold",
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    cursor: "pointer",
  }
}))

const Header = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const {currency,setCurrency} = CryptoState() || {};
  

  console.log(currency);

  // TODO: Gandire sistem reintoarcere pagina principala 
  const handleClick = () => navigate.push('/'); // nu merge - reintoarcere la pagian principala


  // FIXME: Creeare template temă
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette:{
      primary: {
        main: "#fff",
      },
      type: "dark",
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <AppBar color='transparent' position='static'>
          <Container>
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography onClick={handleClick} 
              className={classes.title} variant='h5'>Crypto Hunter</Typography>
              <Select variant="outlined" style={{
                width:100,
                height:40,
                marginLeft: 15,
              }}
              value={currency} onChange={(e) => setCurrency(e.target.value)}
              >
                <MenuItem value={"RON"}>RON</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"EUR"}>EUR</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"USD"}>USD</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </Toolbar>
          </Container>
      </AppBar>
      </ThemeProvider>
  )
};

export default Header;
```

And this is the *problem*, I don't know how I can fix them.
What I want?

Image here

[image]

Please help me!

If I change from select with RON or USD or EURO, i want to console.log to can go to the next step.
But it gives me this error (image), and i don't know how i can fix this

EDIT:

Also, from CryptoState i have this code

```
    const Crypto = createContext();

const CryptoContext = ({children}) => {

 const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("RON");
 const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("RON");

  useEffect(() => {
      if(currency === "RON") setSymbol("RON");
      else if(currency === "EUR") setSymbol("€");
      else if(currency === "USD") setSymbol("$");
  },[currency]);

return <Crypto.Provider value={{currency,symbol,setCurrency}}>{children}</Crypto.Provider>
};


export default CryptoContext;

export const CryptoState = () => {
    useContext(Crypto);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change that line

```
 const {currency,setCurrency} = CryptoState() || {};
```

to

```
 const [currency,setCurrency] =useState(CryptoState() || {}) ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but after I change with this line , It given me some *error yellow* -> https://prnt.sc/NJsdDacm-12q , I can fixed this also ?

Comment: You have to provide a value in the select component within "EUR","RON","USD" so either change useState(CryptoState() || {}) to useState(CryptoState() || ""RON") or change value ={currency} to value = "RON"